# Windows Phone 7 Manage files

Tags: file, windows-phone-7, local

I have storaged a web in the phone using the isolated storage and now It has to download pdf into the phone and be able to transfer it to a PC.

Since the isolated storage only let you use the files of an app in that same app, it is posible to accomplish what i want in Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Windows Phone OS uses the Sandbox principle witch isolates app data so that other apps cannot access and/or modify other app's data.

The only public part of WP app are known libraries as mediaLibrary and in some WindowsPhone versions Documents Library

Check this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681698(v=vs.105).aspx