# Save file in Windows Phone (pdf, csv)

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, storage

I'm trying to find way to save files (pdf or csv) presented in application.
I want those files be available from outside the app.
From what I know it is impossible to save file to sdcard, only in isolated storage.
There is nothing like file manager in Windows Phone, right? 
Maybe there is possibility to save file to some cloud from app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984537/windows-phone-7-manage-files/23041077#23041077

Answer (score 0):

Saving outside of your app doesn't appear to be coming until WP8.1.

In WP8 we do have a few alternatives.

1. Save the PDF locally and [launch the associated app for viewing as per this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17615980/269608).
2. Use a cloud service for saving the file. The easiest way I've come across is integrating with the [CloudSix](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/cloudsix-for-dropbox/4d56ec15-bfaf-49c8-bb0e-522089b67518) app for Dropbox. The details on [how to integrate the nuget package are here](http://www.rudyhuyn.com/blog/2014/03/05/cloudsix-api-add-cloud-storage-support-to-your-app-in-a-nutshell/). It's fairly simple if you just need fire-and-forget saving.